# reveal.js working/bootstrap example

Tags: javascript, github, reveal.js

I found reveal.js but I couldn't find a simple working example.
I found [this](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/wiki/Example-Presentations) but they are either too complex or cannot find the source.

Does anyone have a simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reveal.js repository on GitHub](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) is in itself a demo for a simple presentation.

You can simply fork the project on GitHub, clone the fork to your local file system and edit the [index.html](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/index.html) file in the root directory to get started with your presentation.

I myself have created several presentations this way, most recently this one: https://github.com/pahund/devugees-prez-oct2017

If you create your presentation on a special Git branch named *gh-pages*, you can even view it online without having to deploy it to a server, for example: https://pahund.github.io/devugees-prez-oct2017/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install all the components (around npm) needed to use reveal.js, you can still use a docker image like [`agiled-de/reveal.js-docker`](https://github.com/agiled-de/reveal.js-docker)

> This images makes it easy to use reveal.js with docker. It supports the use of the following plugins:
>
> - [**MathJax**](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#mathjax) Enables you to write LaTeX formulas in your presentations
> - **[reveal.js-menu](https://github.com/denehyg/reveal.js-menu)** Adds a menu to test themes, transitions and jump to slides
> - **[Chalkbord](https://github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js-plugins/tree/master/chalkboard)** Write on your slides or on a chalkboard
> - [**Reveal.js-Title-Footer**](https://github.com/e-gor/Reveal.js-Title-Footer) Adds a footer that will stay on every slide
> - **[Charts](https://gitlab.com/dvenkatsagar/reveal-chart/)** To create charts within your presentation
> - **[vis.js](https://github.com/almende/vis)** To create graphs in your presentation

And it has a [`demo_presentation/index.md`](https://github.com/agiled-de/reveal.js-docker/blob/master/demo_presentation/index.md) included.

Comment: Thank you, this seems too complex for a simple example.

Comment: @ManuelaSavianu The idea, with docker, is to be *simple*, not complex: everything is installed for you.